# Ajax not work exatly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, session

The function Ajax not work exactly on file open:

- $_SESSION variables are undefined
- include('file.php') not work
- Other variables on index are undefined

But the $_SESSION, include and variables work on normal page!
I thinked cause is permission, but I have modified all file width 777 Permission.

I can connect to database, on file open, with direct insert data (not include), but I would use include or the same variables included on index page with include

I post the codes, semplify without other query or tag.
The page is much simply (search users width Ajax on onKeyUp = "src_usr ('function.php', this.value);"), I have:

1) index.php

```
<?php
  require('config.php'); //Variables to connect database
  session_start(); 
 ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" />
      <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
      <meta name="resource-type" content="document" />
      <meta name="distribution" content="global" />
      <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
      <meta name="keywords" content="" />
      <meta name="description" content="" />
      <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache" />
      <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
      <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
      <title>Cerca Utenti</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #DFDFDF; color: #000;"> 
    <div id="over_top" style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
     <div id="over_main" style="position: relative;">
      <table id="mainx" align="center"><tr>
       <td>
        <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><tr>
         <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 70%;">
            <div class="pad8">
         <div onclick="showdiv('users', 'updw');" style="cursor: pointer;">Cerca Utente</div>
             <div id="users" style="display: none;">
              <input type="text" id="src_users" name="src_users" class="i_text" style="width: 60%;" value="Search Users" onkeyup="src_usr('function.php', this.value);" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search Users') this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value='Search Users';" />
          <div id="res_user" style="position: relative; background: #FFF;"></div>
             </div>
            </div>
         </td>
        </tr></table>
       </td>
      </tr></table>
     </div>
    </div>
 <?php
  mysqli_kill();
  mysqli_close(); 
 ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2) script.js

```
var xhttp = null;
function src_usr(wch, wht) {
    try
    {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        try
        {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(oc)
        {
            xhttp = null;
        }
    }
    if(!xhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")
    {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        alert("Your Browser not work width AJAX tecnology!");
    }
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("res_user").innerHTML += xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", wch, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send('rnd=' +Math.random()+ '&user=' +wht); //I have insert Math random for cache free
}
```

3) function.php

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['user']; 
$data = $_SESSION['user_id']; // THIS VARIABLE IS UNDEFINED (only on Ajax function, in normale page this variable is defined)
if (!empty($user)) {
    //include('config.php'); IF I INCLUDE FILE TO GET VARIABLES FOR  DATABASE CONNECT, THIS ARE UNDEFINED AND ALL PAGE OPEN NOT WORK EXATLY
    $connect = mysqli_connect('myhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_database');
    if (!$connect) {
        die($lng['CONN_FAILED'] . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_select_db($connect, 'my_database');
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM user_table';
    $risultato = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if ($risultato) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($riga = mysqli_fetch_assoc($risultato)) {
            $data .= ' ' .$riga['user_nome']. ' ';
            $data .= $riga['user_cognome']. '<br />';
         }
        }
        mysqli_free_result($risultato);
    }
    mysqli_kill();
    mysqli_close();
}
    echo $user. ' = ' .$data. '<br />';
?>
```

I have no solution!

Comment: you have to do `session_start(); ` in `function.php` as well (if session is not already started somewhere else). In simple words you have to start the session in any file that needs it (and any other file included will take it from there)

Comment: Thanks! ...Only one question is unsolved: why, the file to include, not write? (The other variables is not possible to read if not are $_SESSION or $_COOKIE; it is right?)

Answer (score 0):

Write `session_start();` on top of function.php file to call $_SESSION variables..

Comment: Only one question is unsolved: why, the file to include, not write? (The other variables is not possible to read if not are $_SESSION or $_COOKIE; it is right?). Thanks!

Comment: Not because of your mentioned reason, Creation of separate files is useful to create an organized structure of your code.. It totally depends on you, You can write the code in a single file too...

Comment: But why the file include, not write? Because the same problem?